# can you cross join a queried result

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two queries that id like to cross join. Is something like this possible?

```
SELECT concat_ws(' ',first_name, last_name) adopters, d.name
FROM adopters
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT adopter_id FROM dog_adoptions where adopter_id = id)
CROSS JOIN (SELECT name 
  FROM dogs 
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT dog_id FROM dog_adoptions WHERE dog_id = id)) d
```

for context here is the sql fiddle link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/ac120/4349

and the problem was: "Adopters who have not yet chosen a dog to adopt and generate all possible combinations of adopters and available dogs."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you just need the right syntax.  `CROSS JOIN` -- as with all the `JOIN` *operators* -- is a binary *operator* recognized in the `FROM` clause.  So you need to put it there:

```
SELECT concat_ws(' ', a.first_name, a.last_name) as adopter, d.name
FROM adopters a CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT d.name 
      FROM dogs d
      WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dog_adoptions da WHERE da.dog_id = d.id)
     ) d
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dog_adoptions da where da.adopter_id = a.id);
```

You can also get rid of the subquery in the `FROM` clause:

```
SELECT concat_ws(' ', a.first_name, a.last_name) as adopter, d.name
FROM adopters a CROSS JOIN
     dogs d
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dog_adoptions da where da.adopter_id = a.id) AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dog_adoptions da WHERE da.dog_id = d.id)
```

Comment: I see, How come the value after the SELECT clause is a 1, I've seen examples and people saying it can be anything, but just wondering why it doesn't matter?

Comment: @WolfgangTruong . . . "1" is the easiest to type, in my opinion.